# left join Select duplicate keys

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Sales Dataframe:

```
transaction_id, name, customer_id, amount
```

Customer Dataframe:

```
customer_id, customer_name
```

I want to perform left join and on Sales Dataframe and then perform some transformations on Sales data frame rows, missing cusomter_ids. However when I do this,

> sales.join(customer,Seq("customer_id"),"left_join").select(customer("cusomter_id"))

I still get that its ambiguous, I tried using Alias too, but failed, is there a better way to do the same?

Comment: why not just `select("customer_id")` ?

Comment: Okay, the example is not depicting my problem, I actually have a UDF I am applying on the resultant dataframe and I want access specific column

Comment: Just print the schemas with `sales.printSchema` and `customer.printSchema`, you should then see where the problem comes from